# AWS javascript API example to list all user pools associated with an account

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Hi I need AWS cognito javascript API examples which will 
1. return me the list of user-pools associated with the account. 
2. create a new user pool. 
I have searched through most of the documentation, but unable to find any relevant answers. Can anyone please point me to a link/article or help me out with a sample code here.

Answer (score 7):

For list User Pools (you basically require the aws sdk, configure credentials, instantiate the client and call the specific operation):

```
    var aws = require('aws-sdk');
    aws.config.update({accessKeyId: 'akid', secretAccessKey: 'secret'});

    var CognitoIdentityServiceProvider = aws.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider;
    var client = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-19', region: 'us-east-1' });

    client.listUserPools({MaxResults: 10}, function(err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log('successful' + JSON.stringify(data));
        } else {
            console.log('error ' + err);
        }
    });
```

Note that there might be different ways in which you can configure the AWS credentials to call the operation. You do need credentials as this is an authenticated operation. CreateUserPool is similar, you just need to pass the appropriate parameters as JSON in the call.

Comment: The answer is really good. But not exactly what I am look for. Read the question carefully. I need to list user pools and not users. Anyways, I have got the answer and have already implemented it.

Comment: I think so too, Amazon's document is not enough to implement this codes.
This is works, and explain well how to do it.